# Libgdx: Why is my button not showing up

Tags: java, button, libgdx

I am trying to make my button show but to no avail. I have been following the following tutorial online [here](https://goo.gl/Oyos7w). In the tutorial the button shows up after the splash screen. In my code it doesnt show up at all. 
Here is the code for my button.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;

public class MainMenu implements Screen{
    private Stage stage;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private Skin skin;
    private Table table;
    private TextButton buttonStart;
    private BitmapFont black;
    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("Buttons/buttons.pack");
        skin = new Skin(atlas);
        table = new Table(skin);
        black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/black.fnt"), false);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("play.up");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("play");
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
        textButtonStyle.font = black;

        buttonStart = new TextButton("PLAY", textButtonStyle);
        buttonStart.pad(20);

        table.add(buttonStart);
        table.debug();
        stage.addActor(table);
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: i edited following the tutorial 100% but still does not work @m.antkowicz

Comment: ok I'm sorry I haven't notice you have `font` defined

Comment: any suggesstions? @m.antkowicz

Comment: can you provide your `Buttons/buttons.pack` (and .png) and `Fonts/black.fnt` files?

Comment: how would i do that? @m.antkowicz

Comment: best would be to edit question and add links to some hosting with these files (I'm asking you to provide your assets because I've tried your code on some example ones and it seems to be working so I expect that the issue is in your files)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100834/discussion-between-ahsen-rauf-and-m-antkowicz).

Comment: @m.antkowicz please check your chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary due to [discussion about this topic](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100834/discussion-between-ahsen-rauf-and-m-antkowicz):

The problem was not directly in **MainMenu** class *(although there was a little issue described below)*.

As it turned out there were no MainMenu Screen launch in the project. Main class (MalawianCulture) has been calling **Splash** screen but there was no transition to the MainMenu.

Changing

```
    //MalawianCulture
    @Override
    public void create() {      
        setScreen(new Splash());
    }
```

to

```
    //MalawianCulture
    @Override
    public void create() {      
        setScreen(new MainMenu());
    }
```

"resolved" problem - of course it is necessary to make a proper transition from Splash to MainMenu because this is desired flow of application.

There was also a little problem with **MainMenu** class and it's assets. However there was **black.fnt** file for font it was lacking with

```
    page id=0 file="black_0.tga"
    page id=1 file="black_1.tga"
```

image files (.tga is [image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA)). It would be necessary to add .tga files or just comment creating font from .fnt file to make it running.

```
    //black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("black.fnt"), false);
    
    ....

    textButtonStyle.font = new BitmapFont();

    buttonStart = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    
    ...
```

Comment: if you dont mind could you please help me out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836787/libgdx-button-not-responding-to-a-click-listener)